# How to manage thread resource with polymorphism? (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I am trying to implement polymorphism, where the derived class implements a method that is run in a separate thread:

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class Base
{
public:
    std::thread m_jobThread;

    ~Base() { if (m_jobThread.joinable()) m_jobThread.join(); }

    virtual void doJob() = 0;
    void doJobInBackground() { m_jobThread = std::thread(&Base::doJob, this); }
};

class Drived : public Base
{
public:
    Drived() = default;
    virtual void doJob() final { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Drived d;
    d.doJobInBackground();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I achieve this safely without getting a `pure virtual method called` exception?

I want to be able to destroy the derived objects, potentially while the job is happening and have the destructor of the base class deal with managing the thread. but since the vtable of the derived class gets destroyed before the destructor of the base class is run, I get a pure virtual method exception.

I thought of adding a `stop` method in the destructor of the derived class that makes sure the thread is joined. But that defeats the purpose of my polymorphic design, where I want the derived class to ONLY be responsible for defining the `doJob` method and not for directly or indirectly handling the resources of the base class such as the thread...

Any ideas if this is possible? Do I need to change my design?

Comment: You have to change your design. You cannot implement something like this in the base class and make undefined behavior logically impossible: attempting to join a thread that's running a method in a derived class. By the time the base class's destructor executes, the derived class has been destroyed, and this is undefined behavior. You could cut corners, and after constructing a thread synchronize it, so that it executes the derived method before returning from `doJobInBackground`() but this is still shaky and prone to undefined behavior.

Comment: I gotta ask *why are you doing this?* What's the purpose of having a class that you derive to do a job, rather than just passing whatever job you need to a new thread?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez the derived class defines the job, so that different derived classes could define the job differently. The job takes time to complete so it should be run in a separate thread.

Comment: But why do this, when you can already pass any callable object (including a lambda) directly to a thread? Why go through all the work of deriving a new class just to start a thread with a new job?

Comment: - It hurt when I do that. 
- Just don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Sam Varshavchik in his comment above, the reason why you trigger a pure virtual function call here is that the destructor of `d` is run before your second thread has even started executing. You only synchronize in the `Base` destructor. By the time the `Base` destructor runs, however, the `Derived` part of the object has already been destroyed. The dynamic type of the object at this point is just `Base`, because that's all that's still alive and, thus, the virtual function call dispatches to the base version, which is pure. Strictly speaking, you actually have undefined behavior here because the object being destroyed in one thread while another may be calling a method on it violates [[basic.life]/7.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#7.2). The lifetime of your object ends when the destructor call starts [[basic.life]/1.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#1.3), the method call in the second thread does not [*inter-thread happen before*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.multithread#intro.races-9) the destructor call in the first thread…

Just

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class Base
{
    std::thread m_jobThread;

public:
    void join() { if (m_jobThread.joinable()) m_jobThread.join(); }

    virtual void doJob() = 0;
    void doJobInBackground() { join(); m_jobThread = std::thread(&Base::doJob, this); }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void doJob() final { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); }
};

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    Derived d;
    d.doJobInBackground();
    d.join();
    return 0;
}
```

works fine…

Comment: I already mentioned in my question that I can "add a method in the destructor of the derived class that makes sure the thread is joined" which would be better than having the user call a join method. My concern is that even having the derived class to have to manage the thread smells like bad design to me. But your links clarified for me that there seems to be no way around this the way classes are designed. Thanks.

Comment: The question is: why do you have to do it like that, using classes and inheritance, to begin with?

Comment: The base class has some bells and whistles for dealing with some data. And the virtual method is for defining how to read the data (which takes time and so is run in a separate thread). So for example the base class is DataHandler, one derived version is DataHandlerJSON, one is DataHandlerXML and so on to abstract away the data read from the handling.

Comment: "_it violates [basic.life]/7.2._" Incorrect: every method call from a c-dtor violates that clause, whether directly and indirectly. By quoting this clause you imply that c-dtors cannot call a member function!

Comment: @pooya13 Actually your whole idea of forcing together thread *management* and the *actual* computation done by the thread in one class is bad design. These are two distinct responsibilities.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm not sure what you mean. This is not at all about member function calls during construction or destruction which is specified separately in [class.cdtor]. A consequence of [basic.life]/7.2 is that calling a member function ourside of a ctor/dtor can only be well-defined after the lifetime of the object began and before the lifetime of the object ended. As stated in [basic.life]/11 *"[…] “before” and “after” refer to the “happens before” relation …"*. Since there was no synchronization between the threads, no such happens before relation has been established…

Comment: Well, I should clairfy, there was synchronization but not sufficient synchronization to make sure the method call happens before the lifetime of the `Derived` object ended…the existing synchronization only made sure the method call happens after the lifetime of the object began and before the storage of the object was released, but not before the lifetime ended…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel You may be lawyeringly correct but that conclusion is patently absurd and indefensible.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm having trouble to understand what your issue is here. Are you trying to argue that this should not be undefined behavior!?

Comment: The design of that class is clearly broken, it's unfixable and no reasonable language would or could reasonably support it. My aim in life (not really ;) is to strike down your answer with a change to the C++ specification that would allow what every compiler allows in practice.

Comment: To summarize my issue: all parts of (C/C++-threads) semantics are MT-neutral, that is all aspect for core (even lib) are **independent of the exact thread that runs it**: an operation is one thread can be done by another. IOW happen-before is a drop in replacement for sequence-before; exceptions are locks (which must be unlocked in the same thread, but in practice they are often implemented as binary sem that are thread indifferent), obviously thread local variables... So what you have lawyerly established is that c-dtors are the only exception to that rule. That seems exceptionally perverse.