# C++ Inheritance and Pointer-To-Member-Functions in combination with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, inheritance, pointer-to-member

currently I'm working on an implementation of a simple HTTP-Webserver (for practise purpose). My class WebServer needs to have a thread to listen for new connections and different threads for reponse handling. I'm not a fan of the way threads are used in C++ so I want to create some abstraction. Therefor I coded the following for easier object-orientated handling with threads (still work in progress)

```
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>
#include<iostream>

#include "ConnectionListener.h"

class Base {
public:
    void start() {
        thread = std::thread(&Base::run, this);
    }
protected:
    virtual void run() = 0;
private:
    std::thread thread;
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    void run() {
        while (true) {
            std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
}
```

This base class should be some sort of interface. The target is, that one can use the start member function of the derived class and have the run member function of the derived class executed in a new thread.

Now my problem / question:
I've learned that one can pass member functions to the thread constructor using pointer-to-member-functions. This is the reason I used &Base::run. But now I'm unsure if the run method of the base class will be executed or the run method of the derived class. My assumption: Due to the fact that we have a pure virtual run function in the base class, the member function of the derived class is used. **But:** What if the run member function in the base class isn't pure virtual but virtual? Does the execution then depend on the passed object reference (this)?

Hope you can understand what I mean. I'm a bit confused by the concept of pointer-to-member-function in combination with threads and inheritance. The concepts of polymorphism are clear to me. Hope you can help me out.

Greeting,
Tmirror

Comment: Is your question really thread-related?  Why not a simple base class, derived class and a sample call, and see how that works out?

Comment: Related: [How to manage thread resource with polymorphism? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55912946/2602718)

Comment: You can use `CRTP` in order to reference the `Derived` class from the `Base`. Also note, you're going to want to `join` that thread some where

Comment: If you're unsure what will happen, why don't you run the program and see? Try it with both a pure and a non-pure virtual function.

Comment: Make start() virtual( for the base - pure virtual) and implement start() in each child to start what should start. It is interesting what the "&Base::run" actually represents. In c++, there are function pointers for the virtual functions inside the object itself and it is used to obtain the actuall address of the function to call. &Base::run means something in the code segment and don`t know exactly what will happen, since it doesn`t exist ...